# How to distinguish jumps in a ggplot line plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with signals that contain (several) **jumps** and want to distinguish these sections from the actual signal by drawing them as **dashed lines**. The exact positions of the jumps are known.

Below are several ways of (almost) achieving the desired result, but they all seem rather laborious to me for such a seemingly simple task. The main problem seems to be, that there is **no data point between the jump points**, that could be set to 'NA'.

So I guess my question is, is there **a more straightforward/concise** way of doing this?

### Example data and initial plot.

```
library( "ggplot2")

s <- rep( sin( 2*pi*0:9/40), 2)
t <- seq_along( s)
jumps <- ifelse( t == 10 | t == 11, TRUE, FALSE)

ggplot() + geom_line( aes( t, s)) +
  geom_point( aes( t[ jumps], s[ jumps]), 'color' = 'red')
```

[image: Initial]
The jump occurs between index 10 and 11 (red points).

### Variant 1: Split signal into two sepearte lines.

```
s_on  <- ifelse( jumps, NA, s)
s_off <- ifelse( jumps, s, NA)

ggplot() + geom_line( aes( t, s_on)) +
  geom_line( aes( t, s_off), 'linetype' = 2)
```

[image: Variant1]
Most straight forward solution I could think of, but the jump points are missing from the actual signal part.

### Variant 2: Brighten up jump sections.

```
s_off <- ifelse( jumps, s, NA)

ggplot() + geom_line( aes( t, s)) +
  geom_line( aes( t, s_off), 'linetype' = 2, 'color' = 'white', 'alpha' = .8)
```

[image]
Result looks better, but not perfect.

### Variant 3: Append intermediate points for the gap(s).

```
t_jumps  <- t[ jumps]
odd_idxs <- rep_len( c( TRUE, FALSE), length( t_jumps))
t_gaps   <- ( t_jumps[ odd_idxs] + t_jumps[ !odd_idxs]) / 2
s_gaps   <- rep( NA, length( t_gaps))

s_off <- ifelse( jumps, s, NA)

ggplot() + geom_line( aes( c( t, t_gaps), c( s, s_gaps))) +
  geom_line( aes( t, s_off), 'linetype' = 2)
```

[image]
Perfect result, but rather intricate.

### Variant 4: Oversampling.

```
t_os <- seq( min( t), max( t), 'by' = .5)
s_os <- approx( t, s, t_os)$y

jumps_os <- approx( t, jumps, t_os)$y >= 1
gaps_os  <- c( FALSE, jumps_os[ -length( jumps_os)]) & c( jumps_os[ -1], FALSE)

s_os_on  <- ifelse( gaps_os, NA, s_os)
s_os_off <- ifelse( jumps_os, s_os, NA)

ggplot() + geom_line( aes( t_os, s_os_on)) +
  geom_line( aes( t_os, s_os_off), 'linetype' = 2)
```

[image]
Perfect result, but also rather intricate.

---

**Edit:** Here is small excerpt of actual data. 100 data points with one jump between index 50 and 51. The data does not have a time code, but it is sampled continuously without any gaps; i.e. the index can be interpreted as the time code. Consecutive values are usually very close together, so if the difference between two consecutive values is greater than a certain threshold (in this case > 0.5), we have a jump.

```
s <- c(1.11297501465306, 0.998232815600932, 1.00542810484767, 0.882111160457134, 
   0.864832695387304, 0.875465966481715, 0.814592253696173, 0.911200049519539, 
   0.729520738497376, 0.643376989290118, 0.511524957325309, 0.421549461968243, 
   0.499176602717489, 0.638274888228625, 0.641277324035764, 0.822692758217454, 
   0.653877788316458, 0.662919995840639, 0.752974952850491, 0.59309477712959, 
   0.706765754334629, 0.686750632990152, 0.665331035014242, 0.757375655323267, 
   0.754760862141848, 0.597661179304123, 0.765902449004352, 0.66198324309662, 
   0.723390854336321, 0.877095195278525, 1.0325927500613, 1.22280563246459, 
   1.21561478627846, 1.05408674599603, 1.22628475017846, 1.15282000247389, 
   1.14075413802639, 1.16317573199049, 1.29142561722547, 1.3457714674063, 
   1.29182361606508, 1.28387220101431, 1.1401680175215, 1.03548344178125, 
   1.17217653244734, 1.29718279903755, 1.49284766763449, 1.58462042240426, 
   1.53352373661473, 1.5376752092503, 0.709300844464451, 0.740689239930362, 
   0.703234727680683, 0.587989527359605, 0.716839470714331, 0.71350401584059, 
   0.578017875924706, 0.661974735092372, 0.705410783644766, 0.549552099686116, 
   0.438565947301686, 0.457195165939629, 0.292463065031916, 0.144086477160454, 
   0.241596068348736, 0.394813115056604, 0.573318116273731, 0.476153524685651, 
   0.362233571987599, 0.245603948552161, 0.120956567674875, 0.000272847153246339, 
   -0.14302936391905, -0.0648500232025982, -0.135479792486876, -0.183215864375234, 
   -0.0843432129360736, -0.171867656242102, -0.0671323497779668, 
   -0.237922695651651, -0.169482465460897, -0.00180741865187888, 
   0.108692320249975, 0.20488171428442, 0.132713130954653, 0.186498426925391, 
   0.159074306581169, 0.0921048566699027, 0.193063378147781, 0.00139091908931722, 
   -0.0429555546492339, -0.121841486822814, -0.254593643080443, 
   -0.20847160955891, -0.374809342063964, -0.488266025483608, -0.289662906434387, 
   -0.439308459591121, -0.621471555065364, -0.461930149141699)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "there is no data point between the jump points, that could be set to 'NA'"? What does some true sample data look like?

Comment: It means that a jump always happens between two consecutive data points. There is no gap (no missing data) between these jump points. In my example there is no data point between time/index 10 and 11.
If there was an additional data point at the time 10.5, it could be set to 'NA', which would cause ggplot to break up the line into two segments. This is exactly what happens in 'Variant 3', where I insert this additional data point manually.

Comment: Can you provide sample data of the actual signals without the jumps identified? Do you have the associated time for the signals in the dataset?

Comment: I appended some actual data to my post. But I think the specific details of the data only detract from the actual problem. That's why I chose not to include them initially.

If you will, let me give another example to illustrate the problem:
Consider the following step function `s <- floor( seq( 1, 5, .01))`.
How can I (efficiently) stop the vertical lines from being plotted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a **new ggplot geom** (based on `geom_linerange`) I called **`geom_conline`** (for connected line), which essentially is a `geom_line` with the added **attribute `con`** (for connection). It takes a **boolean vector** in which you can specify for each point, **if it should be connected** to the next point.

*This slightly changes the format of the vector denoting the discontinuities (formerly 'jumps', now 'connections' in the examples).*

```
s <- rep( sin( 2*pi*0:9/40), 2)
t <- seq_along( s)
connections <- ifelse( t == 10, FALSE, TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_conline( aes( t, s, 'con' = connections)) +
  geom_conline( aes( t, s, 'con' = !connections), 'linetype' = 2)
```

[image]

**geom_conline:**

```
geom_conline <- function(
  mapping     = NULL,
  data        = NULL,
  stat        = "identity",
  position    = "identity",
  ...,
  na.rm       = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA,
  inherit.aes = TRUE
)
{
  layer(
    data        = data,
    mapping     = mapping,
    stat        = stat,
    geom        = GeomConLine,
    position    = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params      = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

GeomConLine <- ggproto(
  "GeomConLine",
  Geom,
  default_aes  = aes(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA),
  draw_key     = draw_key_vpath,
  # required_aes = c("x", "ymin", "ymax"),
  required_aes = c("x", "y", "con"),
  draw_panel   = function( data, panel_scales, coord) {
    # data <- transform(data, xend = x, y = ymin, yend = ymax)
    data <- subset(
      transform(
        data,
        'xend' = c( x[ 2:nrow( data)], NA),
        'yend' = c( y[ 2:nrow( data)], NA),
        'con' = c( con[ 1:nrow( data)-1], FALSE)
      ),
      'subset' = con,
      'select' = -con
    )
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_stem", GeomSegment$draw_panel(data, panel_scales, coord))
  }
)
```